# How to get hours and minutes selector in jQuery DateTimePicker control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I have downloaded and tried the jQuery DatetimePicker control from http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/. This is v2.3.7.

And in the download there is an image attached here which shows the selectors on both hours and minutes. But I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation on how to achieve that. Could someone please point out how to achieve this?

```
 $('#' + subgridid_complete).datetimepicker({
                   format: 'mm/dd/yy H:i',//'d.m.Y H:i',
                   //inline: true
                   mask:true,
               });
```

This is what I get using the code above. Notice that the Hour and minute are not independently selectable.

[image]

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your the JavaScript/HTML code where you use that DateTimePicker? Which Theme did you use?

Comment: This page (documentation): http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ only initialize the object and it works.

Comment: You must to share your code if this is not the problem, we haven't got a crystal ball

Comment: @Thargor Please check the updated question. The theme should be the default theme I have not changed it.

Comment: I remember. I tried that before, too. No example on the page shows a freely choosable time. I switched to the http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ (a jquery-ui-addon). Here, the Time can free choosen, like in that example: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Yes @Thargor, this control works just fine. Could you post it as answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No example on the page shows a freely choosable time. You can use `'step'` to specify for example a 15 minute step in the time scroll-bar.

You can also switch to the trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker (a jquery-ui-addon). Here, the Time can be chosen, like in that example: trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker

Comment: Seems to be the only alternative to choose minutes.

Answer (score 5):

If you want 15 minute intervals try:

```
step: 15,
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation >> For time only

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
 datepicker:false,
 allowTimes:[
 '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', 
  '17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
 ]
});
```

For datepicker with date and time  use:

```
   jQuery('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
   format:'d.m.Y H:i'         
   });
```

datetimepicker4 and datetimepicker5 are textbox id on which you want to open calendar

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this? http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

This contains few examples on how to use the datetimepicker, and also use moment.js with this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that before, too. No example on the documenation page shows a freely choosable time.

So I switched to [jquerUI-timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker). Here, the Time can be freely chosen. Many examples are provided.